# Why acquire real vs forged signatures?

Tags: nazi-germany, forgery

In the movie "Valkyrie" by Bringer Singer, there is an attempt to overthrow the Nazi-German government and the SS. In the process, Colonel Claus von Stauffenberg requires a document to be signed by Hitler. Without remembering the details, acquiring this signature was a great risk.

What are the primary reasons they would go to such lengths to acquire a real signature, instead of forging it?

Key reasons that I can think of are:

- Actually getting hold of a very experienced signature forger, with knowledge of Hitler's signature.
- The goverment detecting a false signature. Would this likely be uncovered easily, or would the signatures be examined for important orders?

General reasons, found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_forgery) on signature forgery, that might uncover a false signature:

- Shaky handwriting
- Pen lifts
- Signs of retouching
- Letter proportions
- Very close similarity between two or more signatures

Comment: Is there evidence that it was important to acquire real signatures?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I haven't been able to find any evidence supporting that, no. Perhaps the requirement of a real signature applies to other, similar incidents throughout history that do have evidence?

Comment: Questions in this site expect to show a minimum of research. In this case, I would say the minimum would include documentation showing that, *in the actual world*, that signature was actually required and the whole thing is not a fabrication to create a moment of tension (believe it or not, movies sometimes are not 100% true to the facts -except for Ghostbusters, of course-).

Comment: If you want a wild guess (again, in movie universe), doing things "legally" would lower the risk for the conspirators: if someone mentioned to Hitler the document approved it would be ok, there would be no forged signature to use as evidence of foul play... The conspirators would have one less risk while they kept their preparations, or if they decided not to put into action.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think it is a history question

Comment: It's a historical problem, even though the specific scenario is fictional. Maybe more suitable for another se, but I can't think of which one. Aspect of politics and crypto, but doesn't fit either well.

Comment: Unless your conspiracy already includes a professional forger, engaging a forger may well be riskier than getting an authentic signature.  How do you know the forger isn't also going to be an informer?  I mean, it's not like his profession inspires confidence in his trustworthiness!

Comment: @CMonsour To my knowledge, forging the signature was never taken into consideration. The following scenario is easy to imagine: Himmler asks Hitler: 'Why was the SS made subordinate to the army in your recently authorized change to the Operation Valkyrie?' Hitler replies: 'What changes? I authorized no changes to the Operation Valkyrie!'. Maybe an interesting plot for an *alternative* history **short** movie version of the film, since the conspiracy would have come to an untimly end soon after that conversation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original [Operation Valkyrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Valkyrie#Planning) plan was developed in December 1941.

> [Unternehmen Walküre](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unternehmen_Walk%C3%BCre) (translated)
> ...
> Soldiers of the reserve army were supposed to occupy important points in Berlin and other larger cities and take action against insurgents.  The activation by the code word 'Valkyrie' was reserved for Adolf Hitler personally and for the commander of the replacement army.
> ...

This plan needed **adaptations** that gave the army a more central role in the operation. These adaptations needed authorization, that was given by Hitler in 1943.

This is the scene shown in the movie.

> What are the primary reasons they would go to such lengths to acquire a real signature, instead of forging it?

To have made the needed changes **without authorization** would have swiftly led to an investigation as to the reason why, which the planners wished to avoid.

---

Although not all portions of the film was considered historically correct, the plot itself and the events at the Bendlerblock are as near as you can get for a Holywood film.

[Peter Hoffmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Hoffmann_(historian)), who is a [Stauffenberg biographer](https://www.heise.de/tp/features/Stauffenberg-Die-wirklich-wahre-Geschichte-3421542.html), was their 'informal' historical advisor.

> [Wem gehört der 20. Juli 1944?](https://zeitgeschichte-online.de/film/wem-gehoert-der-20-juli-1944)
> ...
> Der „Bild“-Zeitung zählte Knopp dann kurze Zeit später jene fünf „Fehler“ auf, die er in Bryan Singers Film gefunden hatte.
> Ähnlich tat dies auch Peter Steinbach, der wissenschaftliche Leiter der [Gedenkstätte Deutscher Widerstand in Berlin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedenkst%C3%A4tte_Deutscher_Widerstand).[7] Nur [Peter Hoffmann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Hoffmann_(Historiker,_1930)), der als „informeller Berater“ am Film mitgewirkt hatte, sah Bryan Singers Werk wirklich als gelungen an.
> ...
> <sub>[7] Peter Steinbach, Historiker Steinbach: Die unsägliche Fehler im Film „Operation Walküre“, in Hamburger Abendblatt, 22.1.2009.
>
> [8] Jordan Mejias, Wir wollen der Welt vom 20. Juli erzählen, in: FAZ.net, 23. Januar 2009.</sub>
>
> > A short time later, Knopp listed the five “mistakes” that he had found in Bryan Singer's film for the “Bild” newspaper.  Peter Steinbach, the scientific director of the [German Resistance Memorial Center in Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_to_the_German_Resistance), did a similar job. [7]  Only [Peter Hoffmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Hoffmann_(historian)), who had worked as an “informal advisor” on the film, really saw Bryan Singer's work as successful.

---

**Sources**:

- [Unternehmen Walküre – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unternehmen_Walk%C3%BCre)

  - [Operation Valkyrie - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Valkyrie#Planning)
  - [Memorial to the German Resistance - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_to_the_German_Resistance)

    - [Wem gehört der 20. Juli 1944? | zeitgeschichte](https://zeitgeschichte-online.de/film/wem-gehoert-der-20-juli-1944)
- [Peter Hoffmann (historian) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Hoffmann_(historian))

  - [Stauffenberg: Die wirklich wahre Geschichte (Interview mit Peter Hoffman) | Telepolis](https://www.heise.de/tp/features/Stauffenberg-Die-wirklich-wahre-Geschichte-3421542.html)